# Is the information returned by get_bloginfo( 'version' ) always the same as the one in version.php?

Tags: core

In the WordPress Core, I see some cases doing:

```
$wp_version = get_bloginfo( 'version' );
```

And other cases doing:

```
// include an unmodified $wp_version
include( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/version.php' );
```

That comment about `including an unmodified $wp_version` makes me wonder what could make the first case return a different value than the second one.

Why would they be different?

Comment: "The first value lives in the database" - actually, `get_bloginfo( 'version' )` uses the global `$wp_version` - [see source on GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.0/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L861-L864).

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly it is the same, but sometimes its not.

The edge case is when a core upgrade is being done. At that point the version in memory is going to be of the "old" version while the file version might be (depending where you are in the upgrade process) the new one.

This is a very remote edge case and as maintenance mode kicks in when upgrade is done it is very unlikely that a plugin or theme will run in to it.

Comment: Makes total sense, thank you!